How do I get the original path of route/endpoint in FastAPI?
Using fastapi, I'm struggling with adding "login_required"(or smh) middleware.
(I think middleware is the best idea, and if I dont get normal solution for my problem, I will have to work with decorators, or some hardcoding like putting hassatr(request.state, "user") in each route)
Of course, I want to keep some pages free for unathorized people,
so my idea was to check request's path if it's in AUTH_PATHS list.
that was working till I've understood that I always have some flexible paths, like
@router.get('/posts/all/{page:int}')

If you know how is it can be done on real prod projects, I'd took that as answer
I've got 4 ideas:

Searching for some magic python/fastapi syntax I didn't know (haven't found, but maybe it is)

Using some python modules, like fastapi in-built pydantic (which has been made for validation, so it didn't work)

Making something crazy, like everytime my database gets bigger and needs more pages to show all posts, it adds 1 to some value in config.py, and updates my settings class in config.py, including every single path there (like '/posts/all/154', '/posts/all/155') etc. (this is pure madness and I believe this would be very unefficient and slow)

Checking which endpoint (function) was called by request. Got this as the best idea (when I was already emptied), but then I couldn't find any information if this is even real.



Hi, I guess if you have an auth user then you can give an encoded session token to the user. Then you can have @router.get('/posts/{user:str}/{page:int}'). Inside the route you have  def return_contentpage(token:str):. You decode this token and get user_id or smth which you can then check agains {user:str} in the path value.

The most flexible way to do this is to use two instances of APIRouter; one for authenticated routes and one for unauthenticated routes; for the ones that require authentication, add a dependency on APIRouter (through dependencies=[..]). This will then be invoked for every request that gets served by that router, and your dependency should then verify that a user is logged in and raise an exception otherwise.

You then register the APIrouters under your FastAPI app object by using include_router. An example of how to use a dependency for user authentication can be seen in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/ - but the implementation can be whatever - the goal is to validate the user (based on token or whatever you have), and then raise an exception if there is no valid user.

Oh lord that's exactly what I would've wanted. Thank you, Mats

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So what I did as a solution, I made 2 separate routers, one of which is being applied dependency for required authentication. Validation of token I after all left on middleware, so it makes current user reachable in both routers. Works pretty well.
